Python: set --enable-shared to be true
I've been trying to set --enable-shared to true but I am having trouble with the installation.
I am on a Windows 64-bit machine and initially downloaded the Windows 64-bit installer here for version 3.9.5: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-395/
However, I had trouble with the libpython library, which I installed using pip and was able to confirm when I ran C:\Users\username>pip list:



Package
Version




certifi
2024.2.2


charset-normalizer
3.3.2


idna
3.7


libpython
0.2


pip
21.1.1


requests
2.31.0


setuptools
56.0.0


urllib3
2.2.1



However, I still get a libpython error when I try to run a file.
I looked online and found that it's because I need to change --enable-shared to be true and found this site with more information: https://www.iram.fr/IRAMFR/GILDAS/doc/html/gildas-python-html/node36.html
The second step asks to unpack a .tar version of Python, which I'm not sure where to find. I thought that was a "Gzipped source tarball", which is one of the version options on the python download site, but it looks like the extension for that is .tgz, which is different.
I've spent the good part of a day trying to fix this issue and am opening this up to the Stack Overflow world for some much needed and appreciated help. Please let me know if you have any pointers because I don't think I'm going in the right direction.
EDIT:
The reason I need the libpython library is because I'm installing embedPy, a kdb/q interpreter to call Python functions (https://github.com/KxSystems/embedPy).
I got the following error:
C:\embedPy_windows-1.5.0>q test.q
KDB+ 4.0 2022.01.14 Copyright (C) 1993-2022 Kx Systems
w64/ 12()core 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Loading custom startup.  Customize in C:/q/q.q
Start timestamp (local): 2024.04.30D15:16:15.860158000
Full display precisions: \P 0
C:/q/help.q
C:/q/c/odbc.k
C:/q/ps.k
'libpython
  [5]  C:\embedPy_windows-1.5.0\p.q:14:
.P.env:not H~P;
.p:(`:./p 2:(`init;3))[L;H;B]]
    ^

The FAQs from the GitHub documentation told me to follow the steps above: https://github.com/KxSystems/embedPy/blob/master/docs/faq.md
Let me know if you have any more questions.

The PyPI package libpython is absolutely not what you want: https://pypi.org/project/libpython/. You should probably state what problem you had that involved “libpython”. Perhaps, for example, you tried to build a module from source, and need a C compiler? In any case, --enable-shared shouldn’t be necessary; it’s usually the default for the packages from python.org.

I'll edit my post above to provide some more background

Did you check key each hsym each`$`L`M#.p to see what that says? Is it pointing at the right Python distribution? Your problem might also be an issue with embedPy itself - consider filing an issue on their bug tracker, or switching to an Anaconda distribution as suggested by some commenters (e.g. https://github.com/KxSystems/embedPy/issues/106).
